# How to change syntax coloring of specfile editor

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to change the syntax coloring scheme for the "specfile" editor in Eclipse?

I use Eclipse for C++, PHP and Web development and have customized the colors for those editors. But I have not found any way to change coloring for the RPM specfile editor.

Eclipse Version: 2023-06 (4.28.0)

The default color scheme is completely unreadable:

[image]

**EDIT I**

Here is a screen shot of the context menu:

[image]

**EDIT II**

Right clicking a RPM spec file in the Project Explorer shows "SpecFile Editor".  Selecting to open with either the "SpecFile Editor" or "Generic Text Editor" both opens the same, unreadable, editor.

[image]

[image]

**EDIT III**

[howlger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6505250/howlger) found the right answer!

[image]

Comment: Does it only support (shudder) Themes? Check its context menu.

Comment: Right clicking on a document opened with the specfile editor has a "Preferences" item. Opening it brings you to General > Editors > Text Editors.  There, you can only change general things like the line numbers, etc

Comment: If you right-click in the editor, is there _Switch to Theme..._ (above the item _Preferences..._)?

Comment: No, there is no "Switch to Theme" item in the context menu.  Please see the screen shot in the question above.

Comment: What kind of editor is this (in the screenshot the editor icon is not shown)? Is this editor from a plugin you have installed? When you right-click on the specfile and choose _Open With_, which editors will be listed? Do you get syntax highlighting in the _Generic Text Editor_ (if yes, there will be  _Switch to Theme..._)?

Comment: As the question stated, it is the "specfile editor".  See the new screenshot added to the question. Installation details also included.  Since upgrading to Eclipse 2023-06 I haven't seen ANYTHING about Themes.  I've been using Eclipse for 10 years but Themes seems missing from this version.

Comment: The [_Specfile Editor_](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.linuxtools.rpm.ui.editor.doc/Linux_Tools_Project/SpecfileEditor/User_Guide/General-Usage.html) is from the [Eclipse Linux Tools](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.linuxtools). The [code for the Specfile Editor is here](https://github.com/eclipse-linuxtools/org.eclipse.linuxtools/tree/master/rpm/org.eclipse.linuxtools.rpm.ui.editor/src/org/eclipse/linuxtools/internal/rpm/ui/editor) and ...

Comment: ... the [default colors are defined here](https://github.com/eclipse-linuxtools/org.eclipse.linuxtools/blob/3569cbb8fda483e6d665d35752e7d8af0756af9c/rpm/org.eclipse.linuxtools.rpm.ui.editor/plugin.xml#L442-L508). It seems the _Specfile Editor_ does not support dark mode yet. Please consider to contribute it. As workaround you can edit all colors in the preferences _General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts_.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll take a look at the XML files.  In the meantime, the color settings were where you said: under General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > RPM .specFile editor.  Not sure why I didn't find that earlier.  If you want to add that to an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Great. I used your screenshot in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Specfile Editor](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.linuxtools.rpm.ui.editor.doc/Linux_Tools_Project/SpecfileEditor/User_Guide/General-Usage.html) is from the [Eclipse Linux Tools project](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.linuxtools). Unfortunately, **it seems the *Specfile Editor* does not support dark mode yet**.

As **workaround**, when using a dark theme, you can edit the colors used in the *Specfile Editor* for syntax highlighting in the **preferences *General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts***:

[image: preferences *General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts]

The *Specfile Editor* is open source and it would be great if someone would contribute the missing dark mode support: the [code of *Specfile Editor* is here](https://github.com/eclipse-linuxtools/org.eclipse.linuxtools/tree/master/rpm/org.eclipse.linuxtools.rpm.ui.editor/src/org/eclipse/linuxtools/internal/rpm/ui/editor) and the [default colors are defined here](https://github.com/eclipse-linuxtools/org.eclipse.linuxtools/blob/3569cbb8fda483e6d665d35752e7d8af0756af9c/rpm/org.eclipse.linuxtools.rpm.ui.editor/plugin.xml#L442-L508).